# How to define "ends with any two letters after underscore" in Twig

Tags: twig

In the following example, this condition includes all `type` elements of an array that do not include `_`.

```
{% for type in array %}
    {% if '_' not in type) %}
```

Instead, I would like to include all elements that do not end with `_any2letters`, where "any2letters" is actual any 2 letters. I examined Twig documentation and wasn't able to find the required syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was solved using:

```
{% if not (type matches '/_[a-z]{2}$/') %}
```

This solution takes advantage of PHP regex syntax.

- `"/"` are used in `Twig` to define borders of regular expressions.
- `"_"` is my underscore as is; `[a-z]{2}` means "2 lowercase letters".
- And finally `$` means that the preceding symbols are in the end of the
  `string`.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21866041)

Comment: I added explanation to my answer. Since it answers my question, I think it's going to be the solution.

Comment: In that case, it's fair enough, with some formatting. :)